# Can I read PDF or Word Docs with Node.js?

Tags: pdf, node.js, ms-word, npm

I can't find any packages to do this. I know PHP has a ton of libraries for PDFs (like http://www.fpdf.org/) but anything for Node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily convert one into another, or use for example a .doc template to generate a .pdf file, but you will probably want to use an existing web service for this task.

This can be done using the services of [Livedocx](http://www.livedocx.com) for example

To use this service from node, see [node-livedocx](https://github.com/kingsquare/node-livedocx) (Disclaimer: I am the author of this node module)

Comment: Not relevant, the question was how to read PDF/DOC files not how to generate one.

Answer (score 16):

[textract](https://npmjs.org/package/textract) is a great lib that supports PDFs, Doc, Docx, etc.

Comment: Note: textract uses catdoc for `.doc` files, and doesn't work in windows.

Comment: node-office is not in active development (npm says end of life), hwile textract is being actively developed as of Sept 2016.

Comment: @NayanPatel this is because of some recent updates. I have a project that depends on that behavior, so I've pinned my version.

Comment: @James_1x0 what is the version you have pinned the version.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like there's a few for pdf, but I didn't find any for Word.

CPU bound processing like that isn't really Node's strong point anyway (i.e. you get no additional benefits using node to do it over any other language). A pragmatic approach would be to find a good tool and utilise it from Node.

I have heard good things around the office about docsplit http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/

While it's not Node, you could easily invoke it from Node with http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#child_process.exec

Comment: The advantage of a pure JS solution is that is it portable between the browser and Node

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest looking into [unoconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unoconv) for your initial conversion, this uses [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/)  or OpenOffice for the actual conversion.  Which adds some overhead.

I'd setup a few workers with all the necessities setup, and use a request/response queue for handling the conversion... (may want to look into [kue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue) or [zmq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zmq))

In general this is a CPU bound and heavy task that should be offloaded...  Pandoc and others specifically mention `.docx`, not `.doc` so they may or may not be options as well.

---

Note: I know this question is old, just wanted to provide a current answer for others coming across this.

Answer (score 3):

you can use pdf-text for pdf files. it will extract text from a pdf into an array of text 'chunks'. Useful for doing fuzzy parsing on structured pdf text.

```
var pdfText = require('pdf-text')
var pathToPdf = __dirname + "/info.pdf"


pdfText(pathToPdf, function(err, chunks) {
  //chunks is an array of strings  
  //loosely corresponding to text objects within the pdf 
  //for a more concrete example, view the test file in this repo 
})

var fs = require('fs')
var buffer = fs.readFileSync(pathToPdf)
pdfText(buffer, function(err, chunks) {
 console.log(chunks)
})
```

for docx files you can use mammoth, it will extract text from .docx files.

```
var mammoth = require("mammoth");

mammoth.extractRawText({path: "./doc.docx"})
    .then(function(result){
        var text = result.value; // The raw text 
        console.log(text);
        var messages = result.messages;
    })
    .done();
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

For parsing pdf files you can use [pdf2json](https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json/blob/master/readme.md) node module

It allows you to convert pdf file to json as well as to raw text data.

Answer (score 2):

Another good option if you only need to convert from Word documents is [Mammoth.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth).

> Mammoth is designed to convert .docx documents, such as those created
>   by Microsoft Word, and convert them to HTML. Mammoth aims to produce
>   simple and clean HTML by using semantic information in the document,
>   and ignoring other details. For instance, Mammoth converts any
>   paragraph with the style Heading 1 to h1 elements, rather than
>   attempting to exactly copy the styling (font, text size, colour, etc.)
>   of the heading.
>
> There's a large mismatch between the structure used by .docx and the
>   structure of HTML, meaning that the conversion is unlikely to be
>   perfect for more complicated documents. Mammoth works best if you only
>   use styles to semantically mark up your document.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing how to download and extract text from a PDF using [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js):

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import superagent from 'superagent';
import pdf from 'pdfjs-dist';

const url = 'http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf';

const main = async () => {
  const response = await superagent.get(url).buffer();
  const data = response.body;
  const doc = await pdf.getDocument({ data });
  for (const i of _.range(doc.numPages)) {
    const page = await doc.getPage(i + 1);
    const content = await page.getTextContent();
    for (const { str } of content.items) {
      console.log(str);
    }
  }
};

main().catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Node.js](https://products.aspose.cloud/words/nodejs) to extract text from DOC/DOCX,Open Office, and PDF. It's paid API but the free plan provides 150 free monthly API calls.

P.S: I'm developer evangelist at Aspose.

```
const { WordsApi, ConvertDocumentRequest } = require("asposewordscloud");
const fs = require('fs');

// Get Customer ID and Customer Key from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud/
wordsApi = new WordsApi("xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

const request = new ConvertDocumentRequest({
                    format: "txt",
                    document: fs.createReadStream("C:/Temp/02_pages.pdf"),
                });
const outputFile = "C:/Temp/ConvertPDFtotxt.txt";
wordsApi.convertDocument(request).then((result) => {    
    console.log(result.response.statusCode);    
    console.log(result.body.byteLength);    
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, result.body);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Deal with an error
    console.log(err);
});
```