# Parse Microsoft Office files in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, doc

I'm working on a web application where users can upload Microsoft Office Document files. Right now, our server is running Node.JS with Express.js and we're hosted on Heroku. Because of this, I don't think that I can install programs such as abiword or catdoc. I can handle the file uploads, but can't parse the contents of the document.

How can I read the contents of the doc file? The information will then be put into a database. It'd be nice to preserve basic formatting (bold, italic, underline), but not essential.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there don't seem to be anything you can get with NPM that will do Word directly, you might be able to use a REST API to request it via another cloud service. For example [Saaspose](http://saaspose.com/) (they of the famous Aspose tools) have public API for [Word](http://saaspose.com/api/words), [Excel](http://saaspose.com/api/cells), [PDF](http://saaspose.com/api/pdf), and others. They list node.js, javascript, and Heroku support on their page.

EDIT:

I see that Saaspose is now called [Aspose for Cloud](http://www.aspose.com/cloud/total-api.aspx)

Another API that claims something similar is [Doxument](http://www.doxument.com/)

Answer (score 5):

[Office](http://github.com/dkiyatkin/node-office) package: `npm install office` seems to provide at least part of the answer. I use it to read Excel files, so far have not tried any Word docs.

Comment: Note: this package seems to convert the input to HTML by running unoconv http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/ (the OpenOffice converter). (For spreadsheets it seems to convert to xls with unoconv, then convert xls->html using http://freecode.com/projects/xlhtml )

Comment: and unoconv requires [libreoffice](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/35446/libreoffice).. how deep does the rabbit hole go? I don't think this solution would scale very well, unless if you wanna install all these applications on all your servers.. which is quite a task frankly

Answer (score 3):

You can use mammoth to parse .docx files https://www.npmjs.com/package/mammoth
and xlsx to parse .xlsx files https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any yet. See below for something that might help.

[Can I read PDF or Word Docs with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038231/can-i-read-pdf-or-word-docs-with-node-js)